# Не могу распарить полученные данные через fetch, они в объекте

Tags: javascript, fetch

```
async getApiMiningData() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/blockchain/mining/calculator?fsyms=BTC,ETH,ZEC&tsyms=USD`
  );
  const result = await response.json();
  this.miningData.push(result.Data);
  console.log(result.Data);
},
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные приходят в объектах, пробовал оператор спред, выбивает ошибку.

Comment: Непонятно как из текста вопроса следует утверждение в заголовке.

Comment: @AlexeyTen , Данные я получаю. Но, они пушатся в виде объектов, т.е я запушил массив miningData, а обратиться miningData.BTC к примеру не могу, потому что он полностью обернут в объект.

Comment: Хм, я запушил что-то в массив, а хочу получить доступ как к объекту. Почему не получается? Ну потому что надо бы изучить основы языка. Хотите объект — пишите в объект

Answer (score 1):

```js
async function getApiMiningData() {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/blockchain/mining/calculator?fsyms=BTC,ETH,ZEC&tsyms=USD`
  );
  const result = await response.json();
  //this.miningData.push(result.Data);
  console.log(result.Data);
}
getApiMiningData();
```

Comment: да, данные я такие же получаю. Но, они пушатся в виде объектов, т.е я запушил массив miningData, а обратиться miningData.BTC к примеру не могу, потому что он полностью обернут в объект. Уже перепробовал разные способы и через       Object.keys(result.Data).map((key) => {
        console.log(result.Data[key]);
        this.miningData.push(result.Data[key]);
      }); результат тот же(

Comment: @ИгорьСолодвоник `this.miningData.push(result.Data.BTC);`

Comment: Мне же нужно все ключи получить, а не внучную их по одному пушить. Да и результат все равно тот же( [{"CoinInfo": {"Id": "1182", "Name": "BTC", "FullName": "Bitcoin", "Internal": "BTC", "ImageUrl": "/ media / 37746251 / btc .png »,« URL »:« / Coins / btc / overview »,« NetHashesPerSecond »: 132670773138950860000,« BlockNumber »: 705259,« BlockTime »: 643,« BlockReward »: 6,25,« TotalCoinsMined »: 18822156,« AssetLaunchDate » : "2009-01-03", "MaxSupply": 20999999.9769}, "Цена": {"USD": 60902.74}}]

Comment: @ИгорьСолодвоник "результат тот же" - какой же?

Comment: @ИгорьСолодвоник `miningData[0].BTC`